# Line-separated JSON using orient=index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas

file.to_json(export_file_path,orient="index")
file.to_json(export_file_path,orient="records",lines = True)
```

I know there is a way to convert some file (i.e .log file) into a line-separated JSON file using orient records, but is there a way to do it using orient index? Because what I'm getting with orient index is just one very long line of text with all the key-value pairs.

Output of json file

```
{"1":{"ts":"1331901011.840000","UID":"CTHcOo3BARDOPDjYue","Source IP":"192.168.202.68","Source Port":"53633","Destination IP":"192.168.28.254","Destination Port":"22","Status":"failure","Direction":"INBOUND","Client":"SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.0","Server":"SSH-1.99-Cisco-1.25\t-"},"2":{"ts":"1331901030.210000","UID":"CBHpSz2Zi3rdKbAvwd","Source IP":"192.168.202.68","Source Port":"35820","Destination IP":"192.168.23.254","Destination Port":"22","Status":"failure","Direction":"INBOUND","Client":"SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.0","Server":"SSH-1.99-Cisco-1.25\t-"},"3":{"ts":"1331901032.030000","UID":"C2h6wz2S5MWTiAk6Hb","Source IP":"192.168.202.68","Source Port":"36254","Destination IP":"192.168.26.254","Destination Port":"22","Status":"failure","Direction":"INBOUND","Client":"SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.0","Server":"SSH-1.99-Cisco-1.25\t-"}}
```

Expected output

```
{"1":{"ts":"1331901011.840000","UID":"CTHcOo3BARDOPDjYue","Source IP":"192.168.202.68","Source Port":"53633","Destination IP":"192.168.28.254","Destination Port":"22","Status":"failure","Direction":"INBOUND","Client":"SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.0","Server":"SSH-1.99-Cisco-1.25\t-"},
"2":{"ts":"1331901030.210000","UID":"CBHpSz2Zi3rdKbAvwd","Source IP":"192.168.202.68","Source Port":"35820","Destination IP":"192.168.23.254","Destination Port":"22","Status":"failure","Direction":"INBOUND","Client":"SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.0","Server":"SSH-1.99-Cisco-1.25\t-"},
"3":{"ts":"1331901032.030000","UID":"C2h6wz2S5MWTiAk6Hb","Source IP":"192.168.202.68","Source Port":"36254","Destination IP":"192.168.26.254","Destination Port":"22","Status":"failure","Direction":"INBOUND","Client":"SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.0","Server":"SSH-1.99-Cisco-1.25\t-"}}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Could you update your question with examples of input and expected output.

Comment: I've added the actual output and the expected output

Comment: isn't it the same output but with linebreaks for each record?

Comment: I was about to say the same @PabloFernandez. The output is the same. It could really be down to what ever IDE you are using to see your JSON in.

Comment: Yes, the output is the same, and I do know that some IDEs do help. However, I'm converting this json file such that it can be viewed in all IDEs and editors with linebreaks for each record, without the need to switch to some other IDE.